# Cron every minute between 12:45 and 13:15

Tags: cron

how can I set cron to run each minute between 12:45 and 13:15?

Is it possible within one cron statement?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need 2 cron statements.

```
45-59 12 * * * /path/script
00-15 13 * * * /path/script
```

Comment: Your condition will run script at 12:15-12:45 and 13:15-13:45

Comment: Not working unfortunately. With this cron it will start at 12:15 - see below log 
`Next fire date is Tue Jul 21 10:15:00 GMT 2020`

Comment: What is your system timezone? @Łukasz

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov, I edited my answer from 1 statement to two statements. Could you review again and let me know if it's still wrong?